# Application Defined or Object Defined Error 1004 in Range.Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to replace cells data with a formula for seven rows but keep getting the subject error in line **"Worksheets("Summary").Range("E16").Formula = "=SUM(Table22[EXTENSION])"** Here is my code

```
Sub HideRows()
Dim lr As Long, i As Long, Tbl As ListObject
Sheet4.Rows.Hidden = False
Sheet5.Rows.Hidden = False
lr = Sheet4.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets("Summary").Range("E16").Formula = "=SUM(Table22[EXTENSION])"
  Worksheets("Summary").Range("E20").Formula = "=SUM(Table23[EXTENSION])"
  Worksheets("Summary").Range("E21").Formula = "=SUM(Table24[EXTENSION])"
   Worksheets("Summary").Range("E22").Formula = "=SUM(Table25[EXTENSION])"
   Worksheets("Summary").Range("E24").Formula = "=SUM(Table26[EXTENSION])"
      Worksheets("Summary").Range("E25").Formula = "=SUM(Table27[EXTENSION])"
       Worksheets("Summary").Range("E26").Formula = "=SUM(Table28[EXTENSION])"

For i = 16 To lr
    If Val(Sheet4.Range("E" & i).Value) = 0 Then
        Sheet4.Range("E" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Does the formula work if you just put it in the sheet manually?

Comment: Yes it works there

Comment: That many tables in one sheet -be it 7 or 28?